# A challenge to get the Bitmap from from url

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I know this question has lots of answers but its a challenge and I want only interested one's to give it a try.

```
http://api.pt-helper.com/ptimages/web/uploads/Median%20Nerve%20Glide%20–%20D%202_300.png
```

Above is the image url that needs to be fetch and displayed in ImageView. The problem is the image isn't loading from the URL appropriately.

I'd like to post wt was challenging as **zgc7009** have managed to find the correct answer and understood my Q.

- In above url there is `–` character that is not a hypen but `EN DASH` with hex code `e2 80 93`    near the end. So it runs on browser but it fails to load on Androi device. Well `Glide` did manged to load it and I must say it an amazing library.

Thanks everyone for their valuable time trying to solve this Q.

Comment: `this question` ??? I see no question. Where is this post about? What do you want?

Comment: @greenapps: I simply want to fetch bitmap from above url.

Comment: This is one of the more poorly written questions I have seen on SO in a while, which is always good for a giggle at least. You have no attempt at trying, you already state `this question has lots of answers` but it appears haven't really tried any of them. I can assure you, a good few of us don't need to try it, we know how to pull in images from the web, the problem is, we used the 10000 tutorials out there before posting a "question" like this on SO.

Comment: @zgc7009: Would you care to enlighten how am I suppose to share a challenging Q on SO then?

Comment: This is not a challenging question, this is Android fundamentals, and there are far too many tutorials, examples, blogs, libraries, etc. to list. When that is the case, the SO question becomes a bit moot.

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal: try it with the url mentioned in Question. I know it'll hardly take 5 mins to do so.

Comment: @zgc7009: I know its not that challenging Q but if u'd try by the url mentioned in Q then I'm sure u couldn't figure out wts the problem is and that makes it challenging.

Comment: If it is challenging why dont you provide a link we could click to see the png in the browser? And.. you failed to tell whats so challenging or which problems you encountered.

Comment: There is no Bitmap. There is a png file somewhere. So what do you want?

Comment: @greenapps: I have update the url. Sorry for previous one.

Comment: There still is no link we can click and you still did not tell which problems you have. This remains a bad post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take back the harshness of *some* of my commenting :P The url you provided does show an image in the browser, but I could not get it to load the image with the Picasso library using the url provided. However, after inspecting the element and utilizing the url from the image source within the image itself, which happens to be

http://api.pt-helper.com/ptimages/web/uploads/Median%20Nerve%20Glide%20%E2%80%93%20D%202_300.png

I was able to pull the image with Picasso.

[image: Screenshot of successful pull]

Comment: So we can conclude that OP did not provide an url to an image but to a html page. Which he could have mentioned as the problem.

Comment: @greenapps that is incorrect. The link provided is actually a png source file, which gets interpreted by the browser into readable html when you inspect the element. It was from within this that I was able to get the url provided in this answer. I would assume the URL encoding for android and/or the library used may not find the url provided valid, though browsers are able to utilize it. This would mean it would show up in browsers, but not in the Android device. I actually find this to be a legitimate question, just maybe not ask very well.

Comment: Sadly i cannot check that anymore as the url now delivers a perfect image right away. Apparently the problematic url has been changedt/tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

I am using glide library to fetch images from URL . I just used the below code

```
 Glide.with(activityRef)
                        .load("http://api.pt-helper.com/ptimages/web/uploads/Median%20Nerve%20Glide%20–%20D%202_300.png")
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                        .skipMemoryCache(true)                   
                        .crossFade()
                        .override(1700, 1700)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(viewHolder.feedImage);

            }
```

In less than a second I got the image!

Comment: Glide does it well. But I can't use third party library for that. I have used httpurlconnection.

Comment: You mentioned u just need to fetch the image . You dint mention not to use any library. Its not a big deal

Comment: I'm really sorry for that :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `Volley's ImageRequest` to get the Image from URL

```
    public static final String URL = "http://api.pt-helper.com/ptimages/web/uploads/Median%20Nerve%20Glide%20–%20D%202_300.png";

    ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {

                    your_imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
        }
    }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(your_activity_name.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RescuingActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

Comment: My app using this, for more than 7 images, It will work

Comment: How about then u post the output image?

Comment: don't forget to apply `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` in your dependencies.

Comment: what output image?

Comment: I mean screenshot of device or emulator

Comment: its simple what u want me to do again, just use this to request image and the responce is itself `bitmap`, set bitmap to your imageView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124040/discussion-between-kevz-and-w4r10ck).

Answer (score 0):

If its heavy image load it in `background thread` using `AsyncTask`

**Note:** Make sure you added internet permission in manifest file.

```
public class LoadImageWebActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageView imgLogo;
    ProgressBar progressbar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        imgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingBar);

    } 

    public void btnLoadImageClick(View view)
    {
        //imgLogo.setBackgroundDrawable(LoadImageFromWeb("http://www.android.com/media/wallpaper/gif/android_logo.gif"));
        new loadImageTask().execute("http://api.pt-helper.com/ptimages/web/uploads/Median%20Nerve%20Glide%20–%20D%202_300.png");
    }

    public class loadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
    {
        Drawable imgLoad;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            imgLoad = LoadImageFromWeb(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(progressbar.isShown())
            {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imgLogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgLogo.setBackgroundDrawable(imgLoad);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Drawable LoadImageFromWeb(String url) 
    {
        try 
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button 
        android:text="Load Image" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="btnLoadImageClick">
    </Button>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/sublayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1">

      <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loadingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </ProgressBar>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_height="200dp" 
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    </ImageView>
  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can u post the output too?

Comment: Plz give it a try with my url and see if ur code works?